# Rearrange misplaced columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to ask about a data cleansing question which I suppose python may be more efficient. The data have a lot of mis-placed columns and I have to use some characteristics based on certain columns to place them to the right positions. Below is an example in Stata code:

```
forvalues i = 20(-1)2{
local j = `i' + 25
local k = `j' - 2
replace v`j' = v`k' if substr(v23, 1, 4) == "1980"
}
```

That is, I move contents in columns `v25 - v43` backward by 2 if the observation in column `v23` starts with "1980". Otherwise, the columns are correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @cd98 Hope you can help on this one!

Comment: I don't understand, if all values of a column actually belongs to another column, and so on, why don't you just rename the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a simplified example to show it works:

```
In [65]:
# create some dummy data
import pandas as pd
import io
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
temp = """v21 v22 v23  v24  v25  v28
1 1 19801923 1 5 8
1 1 20003 1 5 8
1 1 9129389 1 5 8
1 1 1980 1 5 8
1 1 1923 2 5 8
1 1 9128983 1 5 8"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),sep='\s+')

df
Out[65]:
   v21  v22       v23  v24  v25  v28
0    1    1  19801923    1    5    8
1    1    1     20003    1    5    8
2    1    1   9129389    1    5    8
3    1    1      1980    1    5    8
4    1    1      1923    2    5    8
5    1    1   9128983    1    5    8

In [68]:
# I have to convert my data to a string in order for this to work, it may not be necessary for you in which case the following commented out line would work for you:
#df.v23.str.startswith('1980')
df.v23.astype(str).str.startswith('1980')
Out[68]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: v23, dtype: bool
In [70]:
# now we can call shift by 2 along the column axis to assign the values back

df.loc[df.v23.astype(str).str.startswith('1980'),['v25','v28']] = df.shift(2,axis=1)
df
Out[70]:
   v21  v22       v23  v24       v25  v28
0    1    1  19801923    1  19801923    1
1    1    1     20003    1         5    8
2    1    1   9129389    1         5    8
3    1    1      1980    1      1980    1
4    1    1      1923    2         5    8
5    1    1   9128983    1         5    8
```

So what you need to do is define the list of columns up front:

```
In [72]:

target_cols = ['v' + str(x) for x in range(25,44)]
print(target_cols)
['v25', 'v26', 'v27', 'v28', 'v29', 'v30', 'v31', 'v32', 'v33', 'v34', 'v35', 'v36', 'v37', 'v38', 'v39', 'v40', 'v41', 'v42', 'v43']
```

Now substitute this back into my method and I believe it should work:

```
df.loc[df.v23.astype(str).str.startswith('1980'),target_cols] = df.shift(2,axis=1)
```

See [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to understand the params